Combine values from columns whose name matches a variable
I have a table with the following names, based on months:



2024M1
2024M2
2024M3
2024M4
YTD




100
125
150
175
(NULL)


110
120
130
140
(NULL)



If I set a variable for one of the months, I need to sum the values of all columns, where the column name <= the variable, into the YTD column.
So if the variable is set to '2024M3', then row 1 would equal 375, and row 2 would be 360.
What is the simplest/most effective way to do this please?  (Avoiding dynamic SQL if at all possible).

"What is the most effective way to do this please" Normalising your design and switching to date values, then it's a simple WHERE, such as WHERE MonthStarting >= '20240301' (intentionally ignored simplest, as changing your design may not be quick, but it's definitely very effective).

A complete [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Should we assume that your table will grow, and it'll later have 2024M5, 2024M6, ... 2025M1, 2025M2, etc, columns?

You can use the for json/openjson trick to dynamically unpivot your columns and then summarize the values. The way the columns are generated makes things harder than it has to be, but that's what you get for pivoting things in the first place. Btw, if you have columns 2023M1, i guess they shouldn't be part of your summarization, since we're talking about YearToDate

Thanks Thom.  But I can't change the table design (it's not my system).
As for the growth of months, the real table will have 12 month columns, without a year modifier, but I'll just be matching based on "M1" to "M12".
I just added the year, as it made it easier to visualise (at least for me)

Ah, so it is twelve constant columns called M1 to M12 and M9 would contain 09/2024 riht now, while M11 would still be 11/2025. (And M10 either one year or the other or a mix obviously.) That makes this easier to deal with. While the design may not be perfect, it is something one can easily work with.

Here's an option that my help.
Example
Declare @YourTable Table ([2024M1] int,[2024M2] int,[2024M3] int,[2024M4] int,[YTD] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (100,125,150,175,null)
,(110,120,130,140,null)

Declare @Year varchar(4)='2024'
Declare @Mnth int=3
 
;with cte as (
Select * 
 from @YourTable A
  Cross Apply ( Select _YTD = sum(try_convert(money,value))
                From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                Where left([key],4) = @Year
                  and try_convert(int,replace(right([key],2),'M',''))<=@Mnth
             ) B
)
Update cte set YTD=_YTD

Select * from @YourTable

Results
2024M1  2024M2  2024M3  2024M4  YTD
100     125     150     175     375.00
110     120     130     140     360.00

If you want an update dbFiddle

Thanks John.
I was looking at an UNPIVOT option as well, maybe using a staging table for the data.
But yours gives me more than enough to work with for a direct update.

A little explanation would improve this answer.

@John, was waiting for you to post so i can upvote :) left([key],4) = @Year might crash though, i'd go for TRY_CAST there too i guess, or change @year to VARCHAR

@siggemannen Good call.  Will update :)
